# Как добавить элемент в определенную ячейку Grid'а? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

Допустим я динамически создаю сетку. Как мне программно добавить в определенную ячейку кнопку?

Comment: @Foggy Finder Есть форма с сеткой(Grid), как мне программно добавить button в одну из ее ячеек? Не знаю как подробнее объяснить это

Comment: @Foggy Finder допустим я бы хотел чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в конкретной ячейке сетки появлялась другая кнопка и индексы расположения этой кнопки на сетке брались,например, из заданных заранее констант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
Button btn = new Button { Content = "MyButton" };
myGrid.Children.Add(btn);
Grid.SetColumn(btn, 10);
Grid.SetRow(btn, 10);
```