# WPF Button без разметки XAML на C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как создать кнопку (Button) в приложении WPF не используя разметки XAML (прописав этапы ее создания в классе приложения WPF на C#)

Не буду вдаваться в детали, просто требуется что бы кнопка создавалась именно на  C# а шаблон xaml был пустым.

Comment: А с чем конкретно проблема? Вроде все просто: создаём экземпляр, устанавливаем свойства, помещаем в контейнер.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я вручную просто не создавал в C# создавать графику не могу свойства нужные выставить, всякий раз  какпробовал кнопка не отображается. Вот и зотел проконсультироваться какие свойства нужно в обязательном порядке выставить

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/590242/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Благодарю, все получилось.